# Set templavoila template with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

Is it possible to set a page's templavoila template with typoscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how the page is configured by TemplaVoila:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = USER
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page
page.shortcutIcon = {$faviconPath}
```

They call the `main_page` function of class `tx_templavoila_pi1` via page.userFunc:

```
/**
 * Main function for rendering of Page Templates of TemplaVoila
 *
 * @param   string      Standard content input. Ignore.
 * @param   array       TypoScript array for the plugin.
 * @return  string      HTML content for the Page Template elements.
 */
function main_page($content,$conf)    {
    $this->initVars($conf);

        // Current page record which we MIGHT manipulate a little:
    $pageRecord = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page;

        // Find DS and Template in root line IF there is no Data Structure set for the current page:
    if (!$pageRecord['tx_templavoila_ds'])  {
        foreach($GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->rootLine as $pRec)  {
            if ($pageRecord['uid'] != $pRec['uid']) {
                if ($pRec['tx_templavoila_next_ds'])    {   // If there is a next-level DS:
                    $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_ds'] = $pRec['tx_templavoila_next_ds'];
                    $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_to'] = $pRec['tx_templavoila_next_to'];
                } elseif ($pRec['tx_templavoila_ds'])   {   // Otherwise try the NORMAL DS:
                    $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_ds'] = $pRec['tx_templavoila_ds'];
                    $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_to'] = $pRec['tx_templavoila_to'];
                }
            } else break;
        }
    }

        // "Show content from this page instead" support. Note: using current DS/TO!
    if ($pageRecord['content_from_pid']) {
        $ds = $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_ds'];
        $to = $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_to'];
        $pageRecord = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getPage($pageRecord['content_from_pid']);
        $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_ds'] = $ds;
        $pageRecord['tx_templavoila_to'] = $to;
    }

    return $this->renderElement($pageRecord, 'pages');
}
```

This function checks the current page or search trough the rootline (TSFE) for the configured page template. The script does not check any TypoScript settings at all so I suppose thats not supported by TemplaVoila right now.

It should not be too hard extending this class with a custom function that will check some TypoScript settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with:

```
includeLibs.lang = fileadmin/user_tvtest.php

page.1 = USER_INT
page.1.userFunc = user_tvtest->main

page.10 = USER_INT
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page
page.10.disableExplosivePreview = 1
```

and in fileadmin/user_tvtest.php:

```
class user_tvtest
{

    function main($content, $conf)
    {

        if (is_mobile()) 
        {

            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['tx_templavoila_to'] = 7;
            //$GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['tx_templavoila_ds'] = 7;

        }

    }

}
```

http://daschmi.de/templavoila-template-domainbezogen-umschalten-gleicher-seitenbaum/